# run a remote ruby script (pass parameters as well) using ssh

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to connect to a remote host and run a ruby script on the remote host. Following is the code that I am using -

```
ssh = Net::SSH.start(host, user)
args = "some argument" //can be any data type, list, string, anything
results = conn.exec!('ruby runfile.rb args')
```

It's not passing args to the file in this  case. I have also tried using double quotes instead of single quotes. How do I send the parameters as well?

Answer (score 0):

- the name of the connection variable must be consistent (ssh ≠ conn).
- You need to send the content of *args* instead of the string `"args"`:
- Double quotes are needed for the `#{...}` syntax to work. Or use `'ruby runfile.rb ' + args` if you prefer.
- Use `#` instead of `//` to comment Ruby code.
- Use `.shellescape` to harden against unwanted (accidental or malicious) effects in the remote shell.

This code does work:

```
require 'net/ssh'
require 'shellwords'

ssh = Net::SSH.start(host, user)
args = "some argument".shellescape #can be any data type, list, string, anything
results = ssh.exec!("ruby runfile.rb #{args}")
puts results
```

Comment: There is a security problem when your args are not hardcoded, but somehow given by a user. Use `Shellwords.escape(args)` to prevent execution of dangerous commands.